# Vuetifyjs variable theme not working at 1.0.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

Follow the guide at `https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme`, I changed theme with the code below, and it worked on `vuetifyjs version 0.13.0`.

I updated recently to `vuetifyjs 1.0.5`, same code, font still works, but all colors are not working after the update.

I suspect this is due to the change in `//node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl` and `//node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/theme.styl` because the variable `$theme` is defined in v0.13.0 but not v1.0.0?

Appreciate on hint and explanations. Thanks.

`# File: //src/stylus/main.styl`

```
/** Stylus Styles */
@import '../../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors'

$theme := {
  primary: $deep-purple.darken-1
  accent: $deep-purple.accent-2
  secondary: $deep-orange.darken-1
  info: $blue.darken-2
  warning: $amber.darken-2
  error: $red.darken-2
  success: $green.darken-2
}

$body-font-family := 'Share Tech Mono'

@import '../../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/main'
```

Update:

Based on the suggestion of Traxo, modify `//src/main.js` with code below makes it work.

```
# Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#5e35b1', // $deep-purple.darken-1
    accent: '#7c4dff', // $deep-purple.accent-2
    secondary: '#f4511e', // $deep-orange.darken-1
    info: '#1976d2', // $blue.darken-2
    warning: '#ffa000', // $amber.darken-2
    error: '#d32f2f', // $red.darken-2
    success: '#388e3c' // $green.darken-2
  }
})
```

Comment: Just a heads-up that It's not a common practice to provide an answer by editing a question. Instead, leave a question as it was without modifying it, because it was a valid question. If any of the answers helped you, consider upvoting them, or mark answer as "accepted" if it solved the problem in question. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated since [v0.17](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v0.17.0):

> **Stylus declared themes** are no longer needed (and **will not work**).
>
> Theme colors are now defined in the Vue.use statement instead of
>   stylus, [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme)

Since v0.17 you have to pass a `theme` property to the `Vue.use` function

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
})
```

(note that values like `"red"` or `"green"` will not work, you need hex values)

Comment: Got it. I modified the `//src/main.js` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using [nuxt.js](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/master/examples/with-vuetify/assets/app.styl) this needs to be in the `vuetify plugin` you write.